# /posts/{id}/revisions breaks for posts with [tag:*] content

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, revisions

Attempting to access (at least) the revisions route for a post with a revision involving the `[tag:*]` syntax causes an error:

- [Example on Meta Stack Overflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/posts/69482/revisions?site=meta.stackoverflow) ([Post History](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/69482/revisions))
- [Example on Mathematica](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/posts/259/revisions?site=mathematica) ([Post History](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/259/revisions))

Comment: I think this is actually a bug with `[tag:*]` syntax, a fix will be out once I can disentangle this...

Comment: Ah ha, I didn't even see the tag in the Mathematica post. I'll update this accordingly, for good measure...appreciate the quick response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it, fix has been deployed.

There was a bit of confusion around loading tag data*, basically trying to get the "required", "mod only", and "sponsored" tags for `api.stackexchange.com`... which doesn't end well.

<sub>*Data necessary for rendering revisions that have the `[tag:name]` markdown extensions.</sub>